# making a div appear and disappear using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/6hvtc749/

Here's the function I'm using:

```
<script>
    function dblock_on() {

                document.getElementById('donation').checked = true;
                document.getElementById('dblock').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('sblock').style.display = "none";
    }
    function sblock_on() {

                document.getElementById('sponsorship').checked = true;
                document.getElementById('sblock').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('dblock').style.display = "none";
    }       
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `#sblock` div in your HTML which causes `sblock_on()` to error and exit before it can change the `#dblock` style. Either remove the references to `#sblock` in your function(s) or add that element to your html so that the scripts don't error/exit before they can finish running all of the code.

```css
#dblock {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
 <form action="" method="post">
 
   <h3>Type</h3>
        <input name="rtype" id="sponsorship" type="radio" value="sponsorship">
        <label for="sponsorship" onclick="sblock_on()">Sponsorship</label>
        <input name="rtype" id="donation" type="radio" value="donation">
        <label for="donation" onclick="dblock_on()">Donation</label>
        
   <div id="dblock">
     <h3>Amount</h3>
     <input name="amount" type="text" class="form_text" size="5px" maxlength="10" value="" placeholder="$0"> 
   </div>
 </form>
 
 <script>
 function dblock_on() {
    document.getElementById('donation').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('dblock').style.display = "block";
 }
 function sblock_on() {
    document.getElementById('sponsorship').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('dblock').style.display = "none";
 }  
  </script>
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know it would do that! :) Thank you.

Comment: @thinkofacard no problem :)

Comment: One small side note to OP: You don't need to write <script> or </script> in the JSFiddle's Javascript area

Comment: @jeffcarey it would be more appropriate to comment on their post with this feedback, not my answer.

Comment: @DCR can you be more specific? Works for me, and I'm assuming it worked for OP. It's pretty simple.

Comment: you're right, it does run. my apologies.  Just that it seems odd you click on the label

Comment: @DCR no worries. yeah it's goofy. they also manually set the input to `checked` in the JS when their HTML will do that automatically since the label `for` attr matches the input's `id`. i'm assuming they have reasons for it outside of the scope of code they provided for the question.

Comment: @thinkofacard btw, if this solved your issue, be sure to accept it as the answer to your post by clicking the checkmark by the answer.